# How to create a vector of vectors?

Tags: c++, vector

I have this code so far:
    #include "std_lib_facilities_4.h"

```
void numbers()
{
    vector<int> first;
    vector<int> second;
    vector<int> third;
    vector<int> fourth;
    vector< <vector<data> > all;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; ++i)
    {
            first.push_back(i);
            second.push_back(i);
            third.push_back(i);
            fourth.push_back(i);
    }
    all.push_back(first);
    all.push_back(second);
    all.push_back(third);
    all.push_back(fourth);
    cout << all[0] << '\n';
    cout << all[1] << '\n';
    cout << all[2] << '\n';
    cout << all[3] << '\n';

}

int main()
{
    numbers();
}
```

How do I create a vector 'all' made up of the vectors 'first', 'second', 'third', and 'fourth'?

Comment: What's `data` in `vector<vector<data>>` supposed to be? Don't you mean `int`?

Comment: Is there a compile time error? Is there a runtime error? Does it just not produce what you want? What is the expected and observed behavior?

Comment: `cout << all[0] << '\n';` doesn't work automagically?? (Also note `vector< <vector<data> >` should be `vector< <vector<int> >`!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you actually have a vector of vectors, whats wrong with your `all` vector? You have other problems with your code:

I assume your data is something like:

```
typedef int data;
```

you have small typo here:

```
vector< <vector<data> > all;
        ^---- remove it!
```

this is wrong:

```
cout << all[0] << '\n';
cout << all[1] << '\n';
cout << all[2] << '\n';
cout << all[3] << '\n';
```

you should iterate each sub vector like that to output all elements:

```
for (auto t : all[0])
  cout << t << ',';
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple. Just do the following:

`vector <vector <int> > group`

Or for readability purposes you can `typedef vector <vector <int> > BigVector` and then initialize as follows:

`BigVector group`

You can use the `push_back()` member function but supply a `vector <int>` as your argument.

Comment: But only if your implementing a class ^^ typedefs in a func will freak the hell out of me; like a snake in the toilet; I mean it!

Comment: I would put a space between > and > to pacify older compilers. :)

Comment: When I put vector< <vector <int> > all; I get "In function void numbers(): template argument 1 is invalid. 'all' was not declared in this scope." When I put vector <vector <int> > all; I get a huge list of errors coming from my std_lib_facilites_4.h file. FYI: this header file is a modification of std_lib_facilites.h from my professor.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want. Whether you want to define a vector of vectors or place all elements of all four vectors in one vector.

If you want to do the first task then it can be done the following way

```
void numbers()
{
    vector<int> first;
    vector<int> second;
    vector<int> third;
    vector<int> fourth;

    for ( int i = 0; i <= 9; ++i )
    {
            first.push_back(i);
            second.push_back(i);
            third.push_back(i);
            fourth.push_back(i);
    }

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> all( { first, second, third, fourth } );

    for ( const std::vector<int> &v : all )
    {
        for ( int x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

If you want to create one vector from all elements of other four vectors then the function can look the following way

```
void numbers()
{
    vector<int> first;
    vector<int> second;
    vector<int> third;
    vector<int> fourth;

    for ( int i = 0; i <= 9; ++i )
    {
            first.push_back(i);
            second.push_back(i);
            third.push_back(i);
            fourth.push_back(i);
    }

    std::vector<int> all = first;
    all.insert( all.back(), second.begin(), second.end() );
    all.insert( all.back(), third.begin(), third.end() );
    all.insert( all.back(), fourth.begin(), fourth.end() );

    for ( int x : all ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```